# Why would the batch script take longer than executing the commands manually

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file

I wrote a batch script to automate starting my development environment, but it's taking super long to execute. In fact, it has actually never finished. It stops after `solr start`. I'm just assuming that if left to be it would finish eventually.

Is there any reason why it wouldn't continue to execute after `solr start`? `solr start` finishes completely, then all that is shown is a blinking underline after the last output line of the command.

Here is my batch script:

```
cd C:\AerospikeVM
vagrant up
cd C:\solr-6.1.0\bin
solr start
cd C:\XAMPP
xampp-control
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
studio64.exe
cd C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\bin
netbeans64.exe
cd C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
player --vm-name "Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560"
cd C:\Program Files\Git
git-bash.exe
cd C:\Users\me\Programs\Program
start notepad Phase2.0_toDoCache.txt
start notepad Phase2.0_toDoList.txt
```

Comment: @LPChip No. The name of the batchfile is startDevelopmentEnvironment.bat. And `solr start` is run completely. It stops afterwards. It finishes the command, I know this because it outputs 
`Started Solr server on port 8983. Happy searching!`, which is what is normally output when the command completes. But it never shows the next command `cd C:\XAMPP`; just the blinking underscore. Also, if I close out the script and run the command myself it completes just fine.

Comment: Yeah, saw that after I posted my comment, so I deleted my comment and posted an answer.

Comment: What kind of file is the `solr` you're running?  Is it a batch file?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it's a windows command script

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes.

Comment: Then I see your problem.  I'll write up an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you simply launch a batch file (or `.cmd` command script, which is [basically the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148991/225906)) from within another batch file, it won't return when the inner batch completes, it'll just exit.

To avoid this behaviour, you can used the `Call` command to call the nested/inner batch file, which will cause it to return to the parent batch file once it's done, and continue executing commands.

From `call /?`:

> Calls one batch program from another.
>
> CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]

So change `solr start` to `call solr.cmd start` and your batch file should continue after launching Solr.

Comment: Good spot. Sometimes the lack of information by the question can make answering it hard. But you saw it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is solr start is starting a program, and your script is now waiting for that program to finish before it will continue.

In order to stop this, you need to use the command `start "title" "program"`

So in your example you would want to replace `solr start` with `start "solr" "solr start"`

Comment: in your answer, what is the parameter `solr` in front of the title program for?

Comment: Huh? Please read http://ss64.com/nt/start.html. `Syntax
      START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`. You should have `"`s around both `title` and `command`.

Comment: Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or just a pair of empty quotes `""`
According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Comment: Ah right, forgot about the requirements for quotes for titles. edited.